# ElasticSearch / Kibana / Logstash: how to split a string in data table?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I have a data table in kibana with data (ingested using logstash).

the log format is something like that

```
"myvals": ["k1:v1", "k2:v3"],
```

the data in the data table looks like this

```
k1:v1       10
k1:v2       8
k2:v3       5
k2:v4       1
```

is it possible to split by ":" to create 2 columns and aggregate by k1, k2, ecc? or what format should I provide in the log to do that

thanks